# Power Query Transpose Table

Tags: excel-2013, transpose, powerquery

Need help to achieve the desired output as shown below. I'm using Microsoft Excel 2013 with Power Query. Please help. Thanks!

**Input Text (test.txt)**

```
Menu1:1>1
Menu2:1>2
Menu3:1>3
Menu1:2>1
Menu2:2>2
Menu3:2>3
Menu1:3>1
Menu2:3>2
Menu3:3>3
Menu4:3>4
Menu1:4>1
Menu2:4>2
Menu3:4>3
Menu1:5>1
Menu2:5>2
Menu3:5>3
Menu1:6>1
Menu2:6>2
Menu3:6>3
Menu4:6>4
```

**Power Query**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\test.txt"),[Delimiter=":", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "Type"}, {"Column2", "Value"}}),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Type"}, {{"DistinctValues", each _[Value]}}),
    Output = Table.FromColumns(GroupedRows[DistinctValues], GroupedRows[Type])
in
    Output
```

**Output**

```
Menu1   Menu2   Menu3   Menu4
1>1     1>2     1>3     3>4
2>1     2>2     2>3     6>4
3>1     3>2     3>3 
4>1     4>2     4>3 
5>1     5>2     5>3 
6>1     6>2     6>3
```

---

**Desire Output**

```
Menu1   Menu2   Menu3   Menu4
1>1     1>2     1>3     
2>1     2>2     2>3     
3>1     3>2     3>3     3>4
4>1     4>2     4>3 
5>1     5>2     5>3 
6>1     6>2     6>3     6>4
```

Comment: never mind. Actually the proposed solution suits to the described Problem resp. to the wished output, isn't it? Thank you for accepting the solution, if so.

Comment: Yes..the solution were perfect based on the example given. Tq. However Im still looking on more broad solution that can except any value. Again thanks

Comment: help needed...anyone? tqvm

Comment: if I understand the pattern, you want on the rows of the pivot a first value from the 2nd column, which I've splitted by delimiters ">". What could be in your case for a separation mark? A white space, the first word, the x first letters...? Please post a better pattern (as 1>1) in order to understand better your needs.

Comment: @visu-l, please refer to answer below. Another way to achieve the desire output without using the input data. Anyway tqvm. Will be back for more question wrt power query..Stay tune..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from Technet by Ehren-MST. Accept any input value.

---

```
let
        Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\test.txt"),[Delimiter=":", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
        #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Column1] = "Menu1" then [Index] else null),
        #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", "Index"}}),
        #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2"),
        #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
     in
         #"Removed Columns1"
```

---

Change only this code for other data;

```
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Column1] = "Menu1" then [Index] else null),
```

> "Menu1" need to be change to suit your data. tq All..

Answer (score 1):

You can transform desired format in grouped table, which may not be easy.

```
let

Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("c:\testdata.txt"), [Delimiter=":", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
GroupedRows = Table.Group(
                  Source, 
                  {"Column1"}, 
                  {"All", each Table.FromRows({[Column2]}, List.Transform([Column2], each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ">")))}
              ),
ExpandTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupedRows, "All", {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}),
Transpose = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(ExpandTable)) 

in Transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the pivot function, but first split the column2 in order to get the pivot as the desired output.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\test.txt"),[Delimiter=":", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "Type"}, {"Column2", "Value"}}),

//new part
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Column2", "Column2 - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column","Column2 - Copy",Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({">"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false),{"Column2 - Copy.1", "Column2 - Copy.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{"Column2 - Copy.2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Column2 - Copy.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: Yes, it deliver the desire output based on the example. However, this solution does not work if the value contain random value or word. Anyway thanks for the great effort.

Comment: Any other possible way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

[Pay attention to the WeChat Public Number: Excel实战分享](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYhDd.png)

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(Binary.Buffer(File.Contents("C:\test.txt")),2,":"),
    pos=(n)=>try List.PositionOf(List.Distinct(Source[Column1]),Source[Column1]{n}) otherwise 1/0,
    tblTemp = Table.TransformColumns(Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "newCol", 0, 1),{"newCol",each pos(_)-pos(_-1)}),
    tblRes = Table.Combine(Table.Group(tblTemp,"newCol",{"N",each #table([Column1],{[Column2]})},0,(x,y)=>Number.From(y<0))[N])
in
    tblRes
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way, Hope this may work for you.

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Desktop\text.txt"),1,"",ExtraValues.Ignore,1252),
#"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Change Type", "Column1", "Column2"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column2", "Column3"}),
#"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Column3", "Column4"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column1", "Column4", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({">"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column4", "Column5"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{"Column1", "Column5"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Column4"}) 
in  
#"Removed Columns1"
```

[image: result]